# Kali Linux on Raspberry Pi Zero | Default credentials fail

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, kali-linux

all.

Checking if anyone can suggest a solution to a problem I have encountered while installing a Kali ARM image on my Raspberry Pi Zero.

I have downloaded the dedicated archived image from https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-arm-images/ (last image in the Raspberry list, for the Zero), flashed it onto a microSD card using the Raspberry Pi Imager and proceeded to boot up. The system boots without problems and I land on desktop login page. However, using the default root/toor credential combination I use with all of my Kali systems does not work.

Any suggestions?